# How to generate the customized key in slatejs?

Tags: reactjs, annotations, wysiwyg, draftjs, slate.js

I'm trying to make WYSIWYG editor that it is possible to annotate about selected text.

Firstly, I used Draft.js. However, it was not suitable for pointing the annotated text using key because entity key of Draft.js was initiated when selections were duplicated.

So, I found the slatejs while I searched other libraries related this stuff.

The slatejs had 'setKeyGenerator' utils. However, I couldn't find any information about 'setKeyGenerator' of slatejs. This util is just setting function like below.

```
function setKeyGenerator(func) {
  generate = func;
}
```

And I didn't know how to generate key using this function.

Then, Anyone know how to use this function or have any idea for annotation selected text?

Comment: You could pass in something like `uuidV4` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't find some key generator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to generate a key to reference an element (block) by, here's what you can do:

```
// A key to reference to block by (you should make it more unique than `Math.random()`)
var uniqueKey = Math.random();

// Insert a block with a unique key
var newState = this.state
    .transform()
    .insertBlock({
        type: 'some-block-type',
        data: {
            uniqueKey: uniqueKey
        },
    })
    .apply();

// Get the block's unique Slate key (used internally)
var blockKey;
var { document } = self.state;
document.nodes.some(function(node) {
    if (node.data.get('uniqueKey') == uniqueKey) {
        blockKey = node.key;
    }
});

// Update data on the block, using it's key to find it.
newState = newState
    .transform()
    .setNodeByKey(blockKey, {
        data: {
            // Define any data parameters you want attached to the block.
            someNewKey: 'some new value!'
        },
    })
    .apply();
```

That will allow you to set a unique key on an insert block, and then get the block's actual SlateJs `key` and update the block with it.

Comment: Thank you, Sneaksta! However, I solved this problem as making own key generator util.

Answer (score 0):

Slate provides a `KeyUtils.setGenerator(myKeygenFunction)` to pass our own key generator. This gives us the opportunity to create truly unique keys across Editor instances.

In the parent that imports this component, pass a different `idFromParentIteration` prop for each instance of `PlainText` component and you should be good. 
Like so:

```js
['first-editor', 'second-editor'].map((name, idx) => <PlainText idFromParentIteration={name + idx} />)
```

And here's a complete example with a custom key generator.

```js
import React from "react";
import Plain from "slate-plain-serializer";
import { KeyUtils } from 'slate';
import { Editor } from "slate-react";

const initialValue = Plain.deserialize(
  "This is editable plain text, just like a <textarea>!"
);

class PlainText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let key = 0;
    const keygen = () => {
      key += 1;
      return props.idFromParentIteration + key; // custom keys
    };
    KeyUtils.setGenerator(keygen);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        placeholder="Enter some plain text..."
        defaultValue={initialValue}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default PlainText;
```